# Фильтры и пагинатор для таблицы

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

Всем доброго времен суток!

Выводятся данные в виде таблицы и необходимо реализовать фильтр по полям (select или input).
Ранее [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) справлялся с поставленными задачами "на ура", но сейчас данных очень много (порядка 20 000-30 000 строк), страница пытается отобразить и зависает.

Есть более "легковесные" аналоги DataTables? В общем-то, по функционалу нужен **пагинатор** и **поиск**.

Comment: а поясните плиз зачем вам сразу 20000 строк выкидывать на клиент?? я себе просто даже представить не могу где это нада, в таком кол-ве клиент потеряется)

Answer (score 1):

юзаю [jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)

Comment: Да его-то знаю. Вот только он не такой уж и простой.

Comment: А что конкретно вам там кажется тяжелым?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, не совсем адекватное решение выгружать 20к строк и заставлять фронтэнд это все обрабатывать. Просто представьте, перебрать с помощью JS 20к строк стандартными строковыми функциями (что, собственно, DataTables и делает). При таком большом объеме данных следуют большую часть обработки делать на стороне севера, передавать все ajax'ом.

По вашей же ссылке есть документация, как это работает.

http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, сейчас идет тенденция на то, чтобы снижать загрузку сервера и более плотно задействовать мощь клиентской машины. Сервер он 1, а вот клиентов много). По поводу того, чтоб юзеру сразу выкидывать 20 к строк - это вообще что-то невразумительное - он в них потеряется. ) Даже если надо , то jqgrid можно сделать подзагрузку данных скролом.

Comment: Это я понимаю, но вот, видимо, тс сразу грузит 20к при генерации страницы. И, насколько я понял, он ищет решение для обработки этой страницы в 20к строк. Вот я и говорю, что DataTables может подгружать все это кусками, и тогда отпадет надобность  генерировать страницу в 20к строк. Вы  переписали мою мысль, но своими словами...

Comment: > Насколько я понимаю, сейчас идет тенденция на то, чтобы снижать загрузку сервера и более плотно задействовать мощь клиентской машины.

Нужно найти золотую середину между использованием сервера и клиента. Всё зависит от конкретной задачи. :)

P.S. Узким местом является сеть. Поэтому нужно по минимуму стараться загружать её, соответственно если пользователю из 20 тысяч записей нужно 100, то лучше прислать только эти 100. Конечно, если ему через полминуты не могут потребоваться другие 100. Опять же, такие вещи нужно в момент проектирвоания решать, они зависят от многих факторов.